# Nodejs Objection.js conditional patch

Tags: node.js, objection.js

I need to run a patch (or an update) in Objection.js, based on a condition. I have this code:

```
if (leavenMachine.ping == true){
   MachinesInit.query()
                .patch({status: 'OK', online:"yes"})
                .where('machine', 'leaven machine')
                .where('type', 'M');
}else {
  MachinesInit.query()
                .patch({status: 'OK'})
                .where('machine', 'leaven machine')
                .where('type', 'M');
}
```

I need to refactor it so that I don't need two queries (one inside the if condition and the second inside the else), but just one, embedding the condition inside the patch method. Is it possible? How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the `patch` object to a variable:

```
const patchData = (leavenMachine.ping == true) ? {status: 'OK', online:"yes"} : {status: 'OK'}
```

Afterwards, just call the query:

```
MachinesInit.query()
            .patch(patchData)
            .where('machine', 'leaven machine')
            .where('type', 'M');
```

You could pass the value of `patchData` directly to the `patch` call, but this way it's more readable.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's exactly what I wanted. I didn't know I can use a variable as an argument of patch method. Thank you!

Comment: I see. In your example the patch method takes as parameter an anonymous object. If you store that same object in a variable and pass that variable to patch, it's the same thing. Glad I could help!